# Compound types with units

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I wonder if it is possible in HDF5 to store physical units together with the components of a compound datatype?

To give an example, consider geographic coordinates. A location can be indicated in different ways. Latitude, longitude and radius may be given in degrees and kilometers but specified in radians and meters is just as good. How can I store this information using h5py?

Comment: The `h5py` interface returns `numpy` arrays.  They don't store units, not even in the compound dtype.  But you can add `attr` (attributes) to the datasets, or even groups.  So you could store information there.   As far as I know, `h5py` documentation is complete, though it will make most sense if you also know `numpy`.

Comment: I am aware that structured numpy arrays only allow to assign names to components. What I onec in a while see are names like `lat [deg]`. For me this is an inadequate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDF5 does not know about units. Therefore, you have to create an appropriate  schema to document the units of your coordinate data. How you do this is really up to you. I can think of at least 3 approaches:

1. Method 1 creates 1 dataset for each coordinate
   -- Units are defined with a dataset level attribute
2. Method 2 creates 1 compound dataset with all 3 coordinates.
   -- Units are defined with 3 group level attributes AND as part of the
   field (column) names
3. Method 3 creates 1 compound dataset with all 3 coordinates.
   -- Units are defined with 3 additional fields (columns) (datatype of strings)
   --  Attributes are NOT used to save Units.

Here is a code sample that demonstrates all 3 methods with a small set of data (10 values of each coordinate). Hope this gives you some ideas.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

long_arr = np.random.uniform(-180.,180., 10)
lat_arr  = np.random.uniform(-90.,90., 10)
rad_arr  = np.random.uniform(6357.,6378., 10)

with h5py.File('SO_65977032.h5', mode='w') as h5f:

# Method 1 creates 1 dataset for each coordinate
# Units are defined with a dataset level attribute  
    h5f.create_group('Method_1')
    
    h5f['Method_1'].create_dataset('Long', data=long_arr)
    h5f['Method_1']['Long'].attrs['Units']='Degrees'

    h5f['Method_1'].create_dataset('Lat', data=lat_arr)
    h5f['Method_1']['Lat'].attrs['Units']='Degrees'

    h5f['Method_1'].create_dataset('Radius', data=rad_arr)
    h5f['Method_1']['Radius'].attrs['Units']='km'

# Method 2 creates 1 compound dataset with all 3 coordinates.
# Units are defined with 3 group level attributes AND as part of the field (column) names    
    h5f.create_group('Method_2')

    llr_dt = [ ('Long(Deg)', float), ('Lat(Deg)', float), ('Radius(km)', float)  ]

    h5f['Method_2'].create_dataset('Coords', dtype=llr_dt, shape=(10,))
    h5f['Method_2']['Coords']['Long(Deg)'] = long_arr
    h5f['Method_2']['Coords'].attrs['Long Units']='Degrees'

    h5f['Method_2']['Coords']['Lat(Deg)'] = lat_arr
    h5f['Method_2']['Coords'].attrs['Lat Units']='Degrees'

    h5f['Method_2']['Coords']['Radius(km)'] = rad_arr   
    h5f['Method_2']['Coords'].attrs['Radius Units']='km'
    
# Method 3 creates 1 compound dataset with all 3 coordinates.
# Units are defined with 3 additional fields (columns) (datatype of strings)
# Attributes are NOT used to save Units.
    h5f.create_group('Method_3')

    llru_dt = [ ('Long', float),  ('Long_units', 'S8'), 
                ('Lat', float),   ('Lat_units', 'S8'),
                ('Radius', float), ('Rad_units', 'S8')  ]

    h5f['Method_3'].create_dataset('Coords', dtype=llru_dt, shape=(10,))
    h5f['Method_3']['Coords']['Long'] = long_arr
    h5f['Method_3']['Coords']['Long_units'] = [ 'Degree' for _ in range(10) ]

    h5f['Method_3']['Coords']['Lat'] = lat_arr
    h5f['Method_3']['Coords']['Lat_units'] = [ 'Degree' for _ in range(10) ]

    h5f['Method_3']['Coords']['Radius'] = rad_arr
    h5f['Method_3']['Coords']['Rad_units'] = [ 'km' for _ in range(10) ]
```

Comment: For my application I prefer method 2. Is there any change to relate attributes and fields?

Comment: If I understand, you want to be sure the unit labels are consistent for attributes and fields. In other words, if you have a field named 'Long(Deg)' there is a matching attribute of 'Long Units'='Degrees'? If so, I don't of a mechanism in HDF5. Best I can think of is to define the unit label as a string variable, then reference it when creating the label and the attribute.